# Property accessor for maplike object

Tags: typescript

It's not uncommon to have an interface (e.g. via library definitions) that can contain arbitrary data, like this:

```
interface Something {
  name: string;
  data: { [key: string]: any };
}
```

The issue I have is that Typescript errors when I try to access or set values on objects with arbitrary values.

```
let a: Something = {
  name: 'foo',
  data: { bar: 123 }
};

// Below errors with: 'Property "bar" does not exist on type {[key:string]: any}'
console.log(a.data.bar);
a.data.bar = 234;
```

Is this a bug in Typescript or is there an easy way to avoid errors like this?

[This Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20someCondition%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20View%20%7B%0D%0A%09%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20v%3A%20View%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09foo%3A%20'fooView'%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(someCondition)%20%7B%0D%0A%09v.bar%20%3D%20'barView'%3B%09%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconsole.log(v.foo)%3B%0D%0A) illustrates the issue clearly.

**Edit**

I'm looking for an option that hopefully will not make me have to rewrite the entire codebase from `a.data.bar` to `a.data['bar']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define the type to be indexable then you need to access the properties like so:

```
a["data"].bar
```

Your playground example: [modified to work properly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20someCondition%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20View%20%7B%0D%0A%09%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20v%3A%20View%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09foo%3A%20'fooView'%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(someCondition)%20%7B%0D%0A%09v%5B%22bar%22%5D%20%3D%20'barView'%3B%09%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconsole.log(v%5B%22foo%22%5D)%3B%0D%0A).

More on [Indexable Types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).

---

Let's start with the problem:

```
interface Something {
    name: string;
    data: { [key: string]: any };
}
```

In your `Something` interface there's on specific property name `name` of type `string`, so the compiler knows what this means:

```
let a: Something = ...
console.log(a.name);
```

But, if I do `console.log(a["unknownKey"])` then how could it know what's this `unknownKey`? Is it a valid property in the object? What's it's type?
The compiler can't know because you haven't specified that this object has this key and that's why you're forced to use the index notation.

How to workaround this?
Well, you can define the properties that you know that are there and that you already use in your code, for example if you use the properties `name`, `id` and `address` then have this in your interface:

```
interface Something {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    address: string;
    data: { [key: string]: any };
}
```

Other properties can stay as indexes.

You can also use classes:

```
interface Something {
    name: string;
    data: { [key: string]: any };
}

class MySomething {
    public name: string;
    public else: string;

    constructor(obj: Something) {
        this.name = obj.name;
        this.else = obj["else"];
    }
}
```

Another option of course is to just use `any` which bypass the type check of the compiler:

```
let a: any = ...
console.log(a.myProperty);
```

That's obviously not a good solution, but if you use it only where you have friction with migrating old code to typescript then you can use it until you come up with a better solution that fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've seen this approach before, but it seems flawed to me. I am trying to convert a small project to Typescript, and a library has an interface like in my question. So I will need to go trough all files and convert from the preferred`obj.prop` to `obj['prop']`?

Also, this option also leaves me with no code completion. This isn't super important right now, but I feel like rewriting my code this way is strictly worse.

Comment: @Csvn There's no simple solution for this, but I edited my answer with a few options that you have.

Comment: Well, I can't seem to find a solution other than the one you provided. The only other options seems to be to change/override `{ [key: string]: any }` to `any`, which is less clear.

Comment: Saw your updated answer right after I added my comment. Yeah, I guess it's best to see if I can extend the interface somewhere with my own properties. It's just not very clear where to do that when the interface is provided by another library.

Comment: @Csvn Then just use the interface as provided and have a class that wraps the interface and exposes the properties how ever you like them exposed.

Answer (score 0):

Your options include:

```
(a as any).data.bar
(a.data as any).bar
```

or, you could redefine the `Something` interface to be

```
interface Something {
  name: string;
  data: any;
}
```

all of which do, yes, sacrifice some type checking.